# Error when trying to get to a bookmark in word doc using VBA- Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a chat in excel and paste it in a word doc at the position of a bookmark "1".

the macro would die at 'Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="1"'

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
'open the word file 
    objWord.Documents.Open "N:\Template\Template.docx"
    objWord.Visible = True

'create and format the chart
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 
    Range("A:A,C:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$C:$C")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"

'copy the chart
    ActiveChart.Parent.Copy

    objWord.Activate
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   'go to the bookmark in the word doc
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="1"

    'paste the chart
    objWord.Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Word object model library in your VBA project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="1"
```

should be

```
objSelection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="1"
```

Have you added a reference to the Word object model library in your VBA project?  If not, you cannot use constants from word like `wdGoToBookmark` - you either need to define them in your Excel VBA or replace them with their numeric value.