# Bad Parameter when using objSelection.EndKey to move to the bottom of a word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to move the cursor to the very end of a word doc and paste a chart. But i'm getting an error message of "Bad Parameter" on this line "objSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory"

```
 Dim objWord As Object
 Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

 objWord.Documents.Open "N:\Template\Template.docx"
 objWord.Visible = True
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
...
```

then i had this in a while loop:

```
Do While IsEmpty(Range("A1").Value) = False
...
Range("D:D,F:F").Select 'select date and value

Range("F1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select

ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = subregion & " " & typ & " " & cate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"
ActiveChart.Parent.Copy
objWord.Activate
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection                 
objSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory                                
objWord.Selection.Paste
...
loop
```

The same code worked in a smaller sample without the while loop. Now i am trying to incorporate the code with my while loop and the oibjSelection.EndKey line kills the macro

my smaller sample that worked:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'Change the directory path and file name to the location'of the document you want to open from Excel
    objWord.Documents.Open "N:\Template\Template.docx"
    objWord.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Activate


    Range("A:A,C:C").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$C:$C")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/yyyy"

    ActiveChart.Parent.Copy
    objWord.Activate
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

    objSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory

    objWord.Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] so that we have complete context for testing? As it stands, we can't be *sure* what `objWord` is, nor how `objSelection` is declared. We can *guess* that this is being called from another application, but it's not clear if that's the case, nor which application it might be. It would also be very important to know WHAT is selected at this moment. Possibly, it's something that doesn't allow the action being executed...

Comment: See my question in my answer to your earlier question today.  If that makes sense.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364402/error-when-trying-to-get-to-a-bookmark-in-word-doc-using-vba-run-time-error-43

Comment: i have provided my context to the problem. To Tim Williams, you answered my question earlier but now i tried to used the code earlier into a while loop, and now it is not working again.

Comment: My earlier question was about adding a reference to the Word Object Library to your VB Project - see @CindyMeister's answer below.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800137/how-to-add-references-to-excel-vba-for-word-programming

Answer (score 1):

A more reliable way to get to the end of the document:

```
Dim rng as Object ' or Word.Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.Paste
```

Note, however, if Word is being automated from another application (Excel, for example) *and* there is no reference to the Word object library in that project, that Word-specific enumeration cannot be used since VBA in the other application will not be able to recognize it. In this case, the numerical equivalent needs to be provided instead of the `wd` enumeration. So:

```
rng.Collapsed 0
```

Comment: i got compile error: user-defined type not defined on "Dim rng as Word.Range"

Comment: @lbj420420 Look at the comment to the right of `Dim rng as Word.Range`. Since you provided no context in the question, originally, I could not know which declaration was appropriate when I composed my answer. A certain basic understanding of what you're doing is assumed when you ask questions on Stack Overflow...